# change background with every click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My problem is that when I click on the TR tag, it shows a color, and when I click again, the background color goes, and so far so good.
But when I click again, the color does not show where is the problem??

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
$('.tr').click(function() {
  $('.tr').css("background-color", "");
  $(this).css({
    "background-color": getRandomColor()
  });
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "initial");
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover w-99">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tr">
        <td>654</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you are using `this` correctly. Why `$(this)` and not `$('.tr')` all of a sudden?

Comment: @NanoMiratus Because if I use $('.tr') all of them will change their background together and I Have 20 of tr Tag so i want them to change their background 1 by 1 by my click

Comment: `$(this).click(function() {` every time you click, you add *another* click handler which resets what you've just done.  It doesn't clear the first handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting click events is generally a bad idea as they often don't work as expected.

In this case,

```
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "initial");
  });
```

isn't *replacing* the initial `$(".tr").click` so they both run every time after the 1st click.

One option would be to use `.off("click")` and add the *other* handler, but it's a bit messy.

Normally, I'd suggest using `toggleClass` to set your background, but as it's a random colour, that's not an option.

However, you can still add a class (or use `.data(.., ..)`) to indicate if it needs resetting:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

$('.tr').click(function() {
  // clear rows
  $('.tr')
  .css("background-color", "")
    .not(this)
    .removeClass("random");

  if (!$(this).hasClass("random")) {
    $(this).css({
        "background-color": getRandomColor()
      })
      .addClass("random");

  } else {
    $('.tr').removeClass("random");
    // no need to reset $(this).background-color as reset above

  }
});
```

```css
.random {
  /* nothing here */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover w-99">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr">
      <td>987</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr">
      <td>654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr">
      <td>321</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

just removed a little bit of your code and added the css `user-select: none;` to prevent text-selection after multiple clicks.

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
$('.tr').click(function() {
   console.log(getRandomColor())
  $('.tr').css("background-color", getRandomColor());
})
```

```css
td {
 user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover w-99">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tr">
        <td>654</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

hint: be aware to switch the font color to a white one, when the backgroud is too dark. Maybe there is a jQuery method to detect the contrast.

Comment: No you did not undrestand my question I want to change the background color with one click and the next time I clicked it does not have a background color and the next time I clicked the background color changed from white to random color

Comment: that was not clear to me. You said: `change background with every click`. So please be clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `hasColor` as a boolean to tracking status.

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

$('.tr').click(function() {
  var hasColor = $(this).attr('hasColor');
  if (!hasColor) {
    var hasColor = $(this).attr('hasColor', true);
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": getRandomColor()
    });
  } else {
    var hasColor = $(this).attr('hasColor', '');
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover w-99">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tr">
        <td>654</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr">
        <td>654</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have 20 of tr tag but when i click another one why i have to click twice??

Comment: You have to click twice because there's only 1 toggle and it's only reset when you click on the same row.  Change the last `$(this).css("background-color", "");` to `$("tr").css("background-color", "");` would clear other rows, but there's no check in this code to see if the *same* row was clicked, only that you've clicked again.

Comment: @smmmm I updated the lastest version if you have multiple tr.